# how to get values in each input text and assign to a variable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, loops, laravel-blade

html code like this I want to get all the values in each text area from container-body class
lets assume that I have duplicate elements

```
   <div class="container-body">
     <div class="p-form">
      <ul class="p-formList">
         <li class="p-formList__item">
           <div class="p-formList__item__body">
              <div class="c-input c-input--full">
                <textarea type="text" class="body-text" placeholder="説明記入をお願いします" 
                  name="description" 
                    value="">
               </textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: Why laravel is tagged here? Is this laravel application? and what is issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do

```
var allTextArea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

var contents = {};
for(var i = 0; i < allTextArea.length; i++){
   contents["textarea"+ i] = allTextArea[i].value;
}
console.log(contents); // Will give value in console
```

Now you will get values of this in the form of textarea0, textarea1 in content variable